# Project push to githup working on all projects into workspace

Tags: egit, git-push

I am developing sample android tutorial codes, and I publish them to githup. I noticed that when I publish one of my project, every projects in my workspace has pushed.

**Is it normal or how can I push only one project what I want ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup your git repositories separately in each project directory and it's very likely you set it up in the all projects root directory. And before that you have to setup those projects on githu**b**